# Segue to another imageview for fullsize Image

Tags: swift, segue

I have a photoview controller that displays images in a table view. I am looking for help to segue to a fullsizeimageview imageview controller.  I can't figure out how to do that.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class PhotosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let arrSubCatData: NSMutableArray = [];

    @IBOutlet weak var tblPhotos: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Photos"

        var tabBar : TabBarController = self.tabBarController as! TabBarController
        println(tabBar.parkInfo)


        self.tblPhotos.tableFooterView = UIView()

        var query = PFQuery(className: "MultiImages")

        query.whereKey("placeId", equalTo:tabBar.parkInfo?.valueForKey("objectId") as! String)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                self.arrSubCatData.addObjectsFromArray(objects!)
                self.tblPhotos?.reloadData();
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell

        if let file:PFFile = (self.arrSubCatData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("image") as? PFFile) {
            file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        var imgView : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
                        imgView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToInfo", sender: indexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrSubCatData.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    /*override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showfullsizeimage" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoFullSizeController
                detailViewController.detailItem = objects[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

My newly created fullsize image controller is like this with segue identifier "fullsizeimageview"

```
import UIKit

class PhotoFullSizeController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fullImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What user action do you want to use to trigger the segue?

Comment: Just a simple tap on picture yo segue to full size image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You should add `TapGesture` to the `imgView`.

Your `cellForRowIndexPath` will be now as follow :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell

        if let file:PFFile = (self.arrSubCatData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("image") as? PFFile) {
            file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        var imgView : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
                      //Add Tap Gesture to the imgView
                        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
                        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped"))
                        imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
                        imgView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Now write a handler for `imageTapped`

```
 //When image is tapped
    func imageTapped()
    {
        println("image tapped")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fullsizeimageview", sender: self)
    }
```

And `prepareForSegue` will look as follow :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "fullsizeimageview")
        {
            let destVC = (segue.destinationViewController as? PhotoFullSizeController)!
            let indexPath = self.tblPhotos.indexPathForSelectedRow() //IndexPath for selected table row
            if let file:PFFile = (self.arrSubCatData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row).valueForKey("image") as? PFFile) {
             destVC.imageFile = file

             }
        }
}
```

In your `PhotoFullSizeController` controller

```
class PhotoFullSizeController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fullImageView: UIImageView!
    var imageFile: PFFile!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Load image

        self.imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                   //Set image in imageview
                    fullImageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                }
            }
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Let me know if any issue is there. Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks, in PrepareForSegue section of provided code, it throws an error "Cannot invoke indexPathForSelectedRow with no arguments."

Comment: Ok. It is because of your tableview name. So change that line to `let indexPath = self.tblPhotos.indexPathForSelectedRow()` PS: updated it

Comment: Is it working now? If yes then please accept my answer

Comment: I am sorry, i didnt know i can accept answers, i am still new to stack community.  I already did.  Your help is appreaciated. Previous Error is gone.  I still dont have it working, probably something else is in my code. Only if you get a chance i uploaded project here.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4ibf3cco6ojtij/OParks%20Project%20Files.zip?dl=0